# Multiple If formulas are getting ingored

Tags: google-sheets

I'm building a little list with filters. My goal is to find a specific person for a specific job. I have different status for people, which I chose from a dropdown list. For example I have 3 different status for the people I add to the list: Student, Assistant and Intern.

Now I want to filter out specific people with specific status with checkboxes. I'm using following formula which kinda works:

`=IF(B10,FILTER(DG:EB,DL:DL="Student"),IF(B11,FILTER(DG:EB,DL:DL="Assistant"),IF(B12,FILTER(DG:EB,DL:DL="Intern"))))`

When I mark the checkbox with Student, it shows me all Student like I want. But when I also check the box for Assistant, it still shows only the students instead of showing the students AND assistants. What do I have to change to show me always the selected checkboxes?

Comment: Can you have any combination of the three? Because if so, you would need to check 7 different cases (single options, student/assistant, student/intern, assistent/intern, and all 3). In that case, you need to use `AND(B10,B11)` -or any other conditions- and change you filter for each case.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mTZR7JuPATuupx019FiUC5egBFMu-QY9-bc59tfnCHw/edit#gid=293207867

Heres the actual spreadsheet with the current formula in C9. The first critera on the left works (checkboxes in B10 to B13) BUT when click for example the checkbox in B16, it doesn't the respect the set filters in B10 to B13. 

For example: I want to find a student who is in SZ-GSS 14. When I click the check box of these two criterias, it shows me all students and not just the students whos in SZ-GSS 14

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I may be wrong about the layout of your data on the sheet (*you did not provide an example*), but let's say your data looks like this:

[image]

with the formula `=join("|",ifna(query(A10:B12,"select A where B=TRUE"),))` or `=join("|",ifna(filter(A10:A12,B10:B12),))` you can prepare a string to search for data, which can later be used in the `REGEXMATCH()` function or in `QUERY()`

Now you can either use the formula to filter the data from DG:EB range
`=filter(DG:EB,if(OR(B10:B12),REGEXMATCH(DL:DL,join("|",ifna(query(A10:B12, "select A where B=TRUE"))),false))` or `=filter(DG:EB,if(OR(B10:B12),REGEXMATCH(DL:DL,join("|",ifna(filter(A10:A12,B10:B12))),false)`